# My function is only returning first element of the list when called. I am using BeautifulSoup to extract data

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

a python beginner here. I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape the details(title, quantity in stock) of all books in the first page of books.toscrape.com . For that, first getting links to all the individual books has to take place. I have made the function page1_url for the same. The problem is, upon returning the list of the links extracted, only the first element of the list is returned.
Please help in identifying the error or provide an alternative code using BeautifulSoup only.
Thanks in advance!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def page1_url(page1):
    response= requests.get(page1)
    data= BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
   
    
    b1= data.find_all('h3')
    
    for i in b1:
        l=i.find_all('a')
        for j in l:
            l1=j['href']
            books_urls=[]
            books_urls.append(base_url + l1)
            books_urls=list(books_urls)
            return books_urls
            
    
                     

allPages = ['http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html',
            'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-2.html']

base_url= 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/'
bookURLs= page1_url(allPages[0])
print(bookURLs)
```

Comment: You indented the `return` line so it's called after the first one, instead of waiting until the loops have finished.  Also, you're recreating the list from scratch each time through the loop, twice? You need to rewrite that part, paying careful attention to what you want to taken first and what should happen next.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel like such a fool for not being able to identify this haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rewriting the `books_urls` list for each link, and you are returning the function after the first element in the `for j in l` loop:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def page1_url(page1):
    response= requests.get(page1)
    data= BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
   
    b1= data.find_all('h3')
    
    # you were rewriting this list for each link
    books_urls = []

    for i in b1:
        l=i.find_all('a')
        for j in l:
            l1=j['href']
            books_urls.append(base_url + l1)

    # these lines had too many indents
    books_urls=list(books_urls)
    return books_urls
            
    
allPages = ['http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html',
            'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-2.html']

base_url= 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/'
bookURLs= page1_url(allPages[0])
print(bookURLs)
```

```
['http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html', 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/tipping-the-velvet_999/index.html', 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/soumission_998/index.html', 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/sharp-objects_997/index.html', ... 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/its-only-the-himalayas_981/index.html']
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail. Means a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome. I haven't seen `books.toscrape.com` before, so thanks for introducing me to it!